# Hash String to be sortable - big data

Tags: java, c#, sql, mongodb

hypothetical question here.  We have a database with documents, and all documents have a name.  However, our database does not provide natural sort functionality, only alphabetic is available asc/desc.  And we need to paginate data from it while sorting it using natural sort.

Is there an algorithm to turn string into natural sort string that can be then used as a sort column?  Is there such a thing?  Or is there a better way of doing this?

Number of records is too high, so we can't pull all and sort in code.  So trying to see if there is a way to make it sortable without full iteration of everything.

Comment: If you DBMS supports stored procedures, you could use those of course. As I see it MongoDb supports only "stored javascript". Note that Java and Javascript have nothing to with each other.

Comment: Christopher I haven't found a good efficient way to do it via stored proc, because this is a big data issue in my case.  When it needs to sort 100k+ rows, performance hit of running calculations on every row is huge.

Comment: But the performance will still be better if you run it in the DBMS. There is just no argument about it. Doing it in the programm will add *at least* the transmission of the data over the Network to the whole process. It is more likely to also ignore stuf like indexes and all those other neat speedups that a proper DB(MS) has.

Answer (score 1):

Hypothetically speaking you could create a column called filename_sort which would have the filename with any digits padded with 0s. You could then order by on that column.

```
  public static void toFilenameSort(String filename) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)").matcher(message);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find()) {
        m.appendReplacement(sb, String.format("%010d", Integer.parseInt(m.group(1))) );
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString().toLowerCase();
  }
```

Depending on your filenames you may or may not need to make it more sophisticated.

The output of the above would be

```
Filename-11.txt -> filename-0000000011.txt
Filename-2.txt  -> filename-0000000002.txt
```

Comment: It is definitely a bad idea, but given the poor Stored Procedure support it is propably the best one there can be. Just a small improovement: MongoDB does supprot Views. So it does not need to be a real table and can be kept to the DBMS, with all the improovements that entails: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/views/ But with Mongo I am doubting it even has the support to cache View results like these, so a extra column might indeed be faster.